# List of user roles in View using ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I get list of current user roles in View?

I have tried

```
 @inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
 @userManager.GetRolesAsync(new ApplicationUser() {UserName = User.GetUserName()})
```

but it doesn't work, always empty list.

Comment: This list will be empty if the user not attached to a role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
<ul>
@foreach (var role in await userManager.GetRolesAsync(await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name)))
{
    <li>@role</li>
}
</ul>
```